# Preload a named register?

Tags: vimrc

Is there a way to preload a named register in vim?

For example: I would like to have an empty comment always available in register "c". This way I could insert it and quickly add the text.

Comment: Im assuming if this capability is available it would happen in .vimrc or similar.

Comment: "Buffer" or "register"?

Comment: oops... named registers, like a-z (I will edit the post - thanks)

Answer (score 9):

You can edit the contents of any register in vimscript by using "@" before the letter and then using it like a variable.

```
let @c="Your text here."
```

Comment: Better yet: `setreg('c', 'Your text here.', 'v')`.  Assigning to `@c` can be problematic (for obscure reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setreg` function in your `.vimrc`:

```
call setreg("register-name", "text")
```